# Mysql pass empty value to a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a procedure with a date input parameter. I would like to know if is it possible to set a condition which check if input value is empty. I show you my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xxx.yyy(IN l_day DATE)
```

.....

```
 DECLARE l_today DATE;
```

......

```
IF l_day=NULL THEN  SET l_today=CURDATE();
  ELSE SET l_today=l_day;
  END IF;
```

I would like to be able to call this procedure both with an input like:

```
call xxx.yyy('2015-07-01')
```

or with

```
call xxx.yyy()
```

Do you think that this is possible? Thanks

Comment: Not possible in MySql, https://www.google.ge/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20procedure%20default%20parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can set the condition, but you should always pass the parameter to the stored procedure.

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `yyy`(IN `l_day` DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `l_today` DATE DEFAULT CURDATE();
    IF `l_day` IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET `l_today` := `l_day`;
    END IF;
    SELECT `l_today`;
END//

DELIMITER ;

SET @`l_day` := '2015-07-01';
CALL `yyy`(@`l_day`);

SET @`l_day` := NULL;
CALL `yyy`(@`l_day`);

CALL `yyy`(); -- FAIL
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17713/2)</kbd>